# Inheritance constructor issue

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm having a slight issue with some inheritance.

In my base class I have the following constructor:

```
    public Camera(string n)
    {
         name = n;
    }
```

Then in my child class I have the following constructor:

```
   public StereoCameras(string n) 
    {
        name = n;

    }
```

How ever, my child class complains it does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. I'm fairly new to using inheritance like this, and I thought I had set up my childs constructor properly.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to invoke the base constructor:

```
public StereoCameras(string n) : base(n)
{
}
```

Then the assignment in the derived class is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Your child class constructor call is equivalent to:

```
public StereoCameras(string n) : base()
```

since you have not defined any parameter less constructor in your base class, hence the error. Base class's parameter less constructor is called implicitly *(if none is called using `base`  keyword)*

See: [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx)

> In a derived class, if a base-class constructor is **not called
>   explicitly by using the base keyword, the default constructor, if
>   there is one, is called implicitly**

To come over the problem you can either declare a parameter less constructor in base class or call the defined constructor explictily like:

```
public StereoCameras(string n) : base(n)
```

Also from the [same link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173115.aspx)

> If a base class does not offer a default constructor, the **derived
>   class must make an explicit call** to a base constructor by using
>   base.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
  public StereoCameras(string n) : base(n)
    {


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When a class is instantiated the constructor of the base-class is always invoked before the constructor of the derived class. If the base class does not contain a default constructor you must explicitly define how to call the constructor of the base class.

In your case this would be (note the `base` call)

```
public StereoCameras(string n) 
   : base(n)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a constructor without any parameter to the base class. This will solve your issue.

```
    public Camera()
    {

    }
```